# How do i dynamically resize buttons in a row based off the number of buttons in a row in React Native

Tags: css, react-native, button, row, styling

I'm currently trying to dynamically display different rows of buttons that are evenly spaced out from each other. In my code, two rows have five buttons each, and the third row has only two buttons. Since both buttons are being created using the same component, I was wondering if there was any CSS to help me do this properly.

Currently, here is the code for my the button component:

```
const NodesOptionButton = (props) => {
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        bold: {
            fontWeight: '800',
        },
        textWrapper: {
            width: 60,
            height: 60,
            borderWidth: 1,
            borderStyle: 'solid',
            borderColor: '#000',
            padding: 12,
            marginVertical: 8,
            backgroundColor: props.isActive ? '#000' : '#fff',
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            
        },
        activeTextColor: {
            color: '#fff',
        }
    });
```

And I'm rendering the three rows of button through this code:

```
const NPage = (props) => {
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        nodeOptionsContainer: {
            flexDirection:'row',
            backgroundColor:'red',
            display: 'flex',
            justifyContent: 'space-evenly',         
        },  
    
    });

//lots of code with logic

return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <View style={styles.nodeOptionsContainer}>
                {nodeNumberOptions}
            </View>
            <View style={styles.nodeOptionsContainer}>
                {clincallyOccultOptions}
            </View>

            <View style={styles.nodeOptionsContainer}>
                {MSIOptions}
            </View>


        </React.Fragment>

        
    )
```

Is there any suggestions, or would I have to create a new component for that specific button? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want your buttons to always take up the whole row, you should just need to add `flex: 1` to your `Button` component root `View`, and you don't need `space-evenly` in the parent.

*If that's not the case, maybe you should post a pic of the desired design and the current design with problem. It helps understand.*

p.s: another tip for performance...define your style outside your component.

Answer (score 0):

You want the two last buttons to take up the whole row? You can always try to add:

```
flex-grow: 1
```

to your button component.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that but it didn't change anything. I also tried adding that to the wrapper, and it just extended each button vertically, but not horizontally.